# Testing member function, by peeling pairs off variadic macro/template/function?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, variadic-macros

(I'm using `catch` for unit testing, which unfortunately doesn't yet have what it's calling generators to do this sort of thing.)

In `c++17`, is there a way to reduce this:

```
assert(""  == String{""  }.removeLeading(' '));
assert("a" == String{" a").removeLeading(' '));
assert("a" == String("a" }.removeLeading(' '));
assert("a" == String{"a "}.removeLeading(' '));
```

With a macro, template, or function like this:

```
#define MACRO(className, method, arg, ...) \
   for(auto [x, y] : { __VA_ARGS }) { \
      assert(x == className{y}.method(arg)); \
   }
```

So it's shorter like this:

```
MACRO(String, removeLeading, ' ',
   { "", "" }, {"a", " a"}, {"a", "a"}, {"a", "a "})

// or

MACRO(String, removeLeading, ' ',
   "", "",    "a", " a",    "a", "a",    "a", "a ")
```

Assuming that all `...` arguments "`auto`" to the same type.

Basically with no limit on the number of `...` args.  (Maybe could go up to 100?)

Using the first `MACRO()` gives: `unable to deduce 'std::initializer_list<auto>&&' from...` (it also doesn't understand the semantics so strictly breaks apart on `,` tokens, but as long as it's put together correctly, doesn't matter.)

Using the second `MACRO()` gives: `cannot decompose non-array non-class type 'const char*'`

---

Trying templates:

```
template<typename T>
void TEMP(T a, T b) {
    assert(a == String{ b }.removeLeading(' '));
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void TEMP(T a, T b, Args... args) {
    TEMP(a, b);
    TEMP(args...);
}

TEMP("", "",    "a", " ",    "a", "a",    "a", "a ");
```

This at least works, but I don't want `className`, `method`, and `arg` to be hardcoded as `"String"`, `"removeLeading"`, and `" "`.

---

I wonder if there's a way to pull this off with all the new type trait / "meta" templates (not sure what else to call them) that I haven't done much with.  (I look at some of the libraries available in the last year or two, and they almost look like a different language to me...)

Answer (score 2):

This very nearly works:

```
for (auto [x,y] : {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}}) {
    foo(x, y);
}
```

The only problem is that the inner *braced-init-list*s can't be deduced themselves. So we just need to give the compiler a little push.

```
using P = std::pair<char const*, char const*>;
for (auto [x,y] : {P{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}}) {
    foo(x, y);
}
```

And that works. Just identifying the first one is sufficient. Or, for your specific example:

```
for (auto [exp, arg] : {P{"", ""}, {"a", " a"}, {"a", "a"}, {"a", "a "}}) {
    assert(exp == String(arg).removeLeading(' '));
}
```

If you really want to write a macro for that, then it should be clear to see how to do that at this point.

Comment: Works great in clang and gcc.  VS2017 15.5 Preview gives `error C3312: no callable 'begin' function found for type 'initializer list'` as well as `'end'`.  My original post only specified `c++17`, didn't mention VS2017, and of course VS2017 doesn't have all of it implemented yet.  This might be P0017R1.  Do you know of a workaround until Visual Studio catches up to the rest of the world?

Comment: @user1902689 This answer doesn't that feature - the only C++17 feature here is structured bindings. You could instead try `std::initializer_list<P>{{"", ""}, {"a", " a"}, ...}`?

Comment: On clang and gcc, `std::pair<any, any>` can even be used, for anything that can be used with any, to drop having to specify the parameter types.

Comment: Yes, VS takes this, with `pair<char const*, char const*>`.  `pair<any, any>` causes VS2017 15.5 Preview to give an internal compiler error.  I'll file a bugreport on that.  I'll also file one for the original `C3312`, since structured bindings is listed as fully implemented.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want className, method, and arg to be hardcoded as `"String"`, `"removeLeading"`, and `" "`.

If I understand correctly what do you want, the following struct `foo` (with static methods `func()`) could give you an idea (but you have to fine tune details)

```
template <typename C, auto ... Vs>
struct foo
 {
   template <typename R> 
   static void func (R(C::*)(decltype(Vs) const & ...))
    { }

   template <typename R, typename T1, typename T2, typename ... Args>
   static void func (R(C::*m)(decltype(Vs) const & ...),
                     T1 const & a, T2 const & b, Args const & ... args)
    {
      assert( a == (C{b}.*m)(Vs...) );

      func(m, args...);
    }
 };
```

The following is a full compiling example (fail running because `removeLeading()` isn't really implemented; so `abort()` are failing)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

// fake String strict, with fake removeLeading() method, to
// demonstrative/compiling purposes 
struct String
 {
   String (std::string const &) 
    { }

   std::string removeLeading (char const &)
    { return { }; }
 };

template <typename C, auto ... Vs>
struct foo
 {
   template <typename R> 
   static void func (R(C::*)(decltype(Vs) const & ...))
    { }

   template <typename R, typename T1, typename T2, typename ... Args>
   static void func (R(C::*m)(decltype(Vs) const & ...),
                     T1 const & a, T2 const & b, Args const & ... args)
    {
      assert( a == (C{b}.*m)(Vs...) );

      func(m, args...);
    }
 };

int main()
 {
   foo<String, ' '>::func(&String::removeLeading,
      "", "",    "a", " ",    "a", "a",    "a", "a ");
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP compiler doesn't support the `auto` type for template not-type arguments.

So the preceding solution (strongly `auto` based) can't work.

I propose another solution, C++14 compatible, that should work.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>

// fake String strict, with fake removeLeading() method, to
// demonstrative/compiling purposes 
struct String
 {
   String (std::string const &) 
    { }

   std::string removeLeading (char const &)
    { return { }; }
 };

template <typename C, typename ... Vs, std::size_t ... Is, typename R>
void barH (std::tuple<Vs...> const &, std::index_sequence<Is...> const &,
           R(C::*)(Vs const & ...))
 { }

template <typename C, typename ... Vs, std::size_t ... Is, typename R,
          typename T1, typename T2, typename ... Args>
void barH (std::tuple<Vs...> const & tv,
           std::index_sequence<Is...> const & is, R(C::*m)(Vs const & ...),
           T1 const & a, T2 const & b, Args const & ... args)
 {

   assert( a == (C{b}.*m)(std::get<Is>(tv)...) );

   barH<C>(tv, is, m, args...);
 }

template <typename C, typename ... Vs, typename R, typename ... Args>
void bar (std::tuple<Vs...> const & tv, R(C::*m)(Vs const & ...),
          Args const & ... args)
 { barH<C>(tv, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Vs)>{}, m, args...); }


int main()
 {
   bar<String>(std::make_tuple(' '), &String::removeLeading,
               "", "",    "a", " ",    "a", "a",    "a", "a ");
 }
```

Comment: I like both of these solutions.  The other is much simpler, but I like this one better because it doesn't require specifying the in and out argument types.  No idea why someone downvoted it.

Comment: Works great in clang and gcc.  VS2017 15.5 Preview gives errors `C3533: a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'`, `C2672: no matching overloaded function found`, `C2784: could not deduce template argument`, and `C2780; expects 1 arguments - 9 provided`.  My original post only specified `c++17`, didn't mention VS2017, and of course VS2017 doesn't have all of it implemented yet.  This might be PR0091R3 and P0127R2.  Do you know of a workaround until Visual Studio catches up to the rest of the world?

Comment: @user1902689 - loosing `auto` for the type of template values you loose the real advantage of this solution: two variadic list of arguments, one for the `struct` and one for the method. So, the best I can imagine is to wrap one list in a `std::tuple`; non so elegant as in C++17 but (I think) possible. Give me some minutes...

Comment: @user1902689 - one moment: a question: your VS2017 15.5 support `std::apply`?

Comment: @user1902689 - unfortunately I don't know how to apply `std::apply` to a method. Well... there is the good old method based on `std::get` and `std::index_sequence`. Answer improved adding a C++14 solution.

Comment: The `c++14` solution works in VS2017 15.5 Preview, gcc, and clang.  Thanks for the revision!